# Handle submit and change from child component in react

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have two components :

- **LoginForm** which is used to render the form to login in the app
- **LoginPage** which get the data entered in the LoginForm component and send it to a server

For the moment I would like to handle the form submit and the change of an input value. I read these two articles in the react official website to help me :

- https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

But I still don't detect the submit and the change from the LoginPage component when I'm entering a value in LoginForm.

Can you help me to see where is my mistake ?
Thanks by advance.

My two components :

**LoginPage.js**

```
 class LoginPage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        login: true, //switch between Login and SignUp
        email: '',
        password: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(){
    alert("SUBMIT");
}

handleInputChange(event) {
    alert("YOUHOU");
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

    alert("YEEEP");
  }

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.state.login ? 
                    <Login onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/> 
                    : 
                    <Register />
                }
            </div>
            <a
                onClick={() => this.setState({ login: !this.state.login })}
            >
            {this.state.login ? 'Besoin d\'un compte ?' : 'Déjà un compte ?'}
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <Card>
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
              <div>
                <div>
                    <TextField name="email" floatingLabelText="Email" errorText="Champ obligatoire" type="text" onChange={this.props.handleInputChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <TextField name="password" floatingLabelText="Mot de passe" errorText="Champ obligatoire" type="password" onChange={this.props.handleInputChange} />
                </div>
                <CardActions>
                    <div>
                        <RaisedButton label="Se connecter" primary={true} type="submit" fullWidth />
                    </div>
                </CardActions>
              </div>
            </form>
          </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleInputChange` is passed down to `LoginForm` as `onChange` prop and similarly `handleSubmit` is passed down by the name `onSubmit` and hence you need to use it like

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
              <Card>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                        <TextField name="email" floatingLabelText="Email" errorText="Champ obligatoire" type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <TextField name="password" floatingLabelText="Mot de passe" errorText="Champ obligatoire" type="password" onChange={this.props.onChange} />
                    </div>
                    <CardActions>
                        <div>
                            <RaisedButton label="Se connecter" primary={true} type="submit" fullWidth />
                        </div>
                    </CardActions>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```